# Background mining causes crash (pymonero)

Tags: mining, python

Does anyone know what it means that whenever I try background mining either with the wallet or daemon my monero crashes?

To be clear I am using pymonero and am getting the following error when running functional_tests.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrew/denarii/tests/functional_tests/mining.py", line 299, in <module>
    MiningTest().run_test()
  File "/home/andrew/denarii/tests/functional_tests/mining.py", line 50, in run_test
    self.mine(True)
  File "/home/andrew/denarii/tests/functional_tests/mining.py", line 143, in mine
    res = daemon.stop_mining()
  File "/home/andrew/denarii/utils/python-rpc/framework/daemon.py", line 219, in stop_mining
    return self.rpc.send_request('/stop_mining', stop_mining)
  File "/home/andrew/denarii/utils/python-rpc/framework/rpc.py", line 66, in send_request
    res = requests.post(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
[TEST FAILED] mining
Stopping servers...
Done, 1/1 tests failed: mining

Process finished with exit code 1
```

More info: it happens when trying to interrupt the background mining thread...

Daemon logs

```
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.306    D [0;32m/get_transaction_pool_hashes.bin processed with 0/0/0ms
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.306    D [0;32mdo_send_chunk() NOW SENSD: packet=240 B
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.307    I [0;36mHTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /getblocks.bin
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.308    I [0;36m[127.0.0.1:37342 INC] calling /getblocks.bin
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.309    D [0;32mon_get_blocks: 13 blocks, 0 txes, size 1813
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.309    D [0;32m/getblocks.bin() processed with 0/2/0ms
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.309    D [0;32mdo_send_chunk() NOW SENSD: packet=2793 B
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.323    D [0;32mhandle_accept
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.323    D [0;32mNew server for RPC connections, SSL disabled
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.323    D [0;32mset m_connection_type = RPC 
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    D [0;32mSpawned connection #16 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:3
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    D [0;32mtest, connection constructor set m_connection_type=1
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    D [0;32m connection type RPC 127.0.0.1:18180 <--> 127.0.0.1:37346 (via 127.0.0.1:37346)
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    I [0;36mHTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /start_mining
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    I [0;36m[127.0.0.1:37346 INC] calling /start_mining
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    I [0;36m36
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    I [0;36mAddress
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    D [0;32mUsing cached template
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    I [0;36mMining has started with 0 threads, good luck!
[0m[0;33m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    W [0;33mBackground mining controller thread started
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    D [0;32m/start_mining processed with 0/1/0ms
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.324    D [0;32mdo_send_chunk() NOW SENSD: packet=204 B
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.325    D [0;32mDestructing connection #15 to 0.0.0.0
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.325    D [0;32mhandle_accept
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.325    D [0;32mNew server for RPC connections, SSL disabled
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.325    D [0;32mset m_connection_type = RPC 
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.325    D [0;32mSpawned connection #17 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:3
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.326    D [0;32mtest, connection constructor set m_connection_type=1
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.326    D [0;32m connection type RPC 127.0.0.1:18180 <--> 127.0.0.1:37348 (via 127.0.0.1:37348)
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.326    I [0;36mHTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /mining_status
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.326    I [0;36m[127.0.0.1:37348 INC] calling /mining_status
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.326    D [0;32m/mining_status processed with 0/0/0ms
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.326    D [0;32mdo_send_chunk() NOW SENSD: packet=692 B
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.327    D [0;32mDestructing connection #16 to 0.0.0.0
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    D [0;32mhandle_accept
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    D [0;32mNew server for RPC connections, SSL disabled
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    D [0;32mset m_connection_type = RPC 
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    D [0;32mSpawned connection #18 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:3
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    D [0;32mtest, connection constructor set m_connection_type=1
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    D [0;32m connection type RPC 127.0.0.1:18180 <--> 127.0.0.1:37350 (via 127.0.0.1:37350)
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    I [0;36mHTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /stop_mining
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    I [0;36m[127.0.0.1:37350 INC] calling /stop_mining
[0m[0;36m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    I [0;36mMiner has received stop signal
[0m[0;32m2020-12-19 22:34:30.328    D [0;32m1
[0m
```

Comment: You say "my monero crashes" but then proceed to show a pymonero functional test failing. It's not obvious if you are asking why the test is failing or if your monero wallet / daemon are actually crashing (for which none of the output in the question points to).

Comment: Sorry I meant why is the daemon crashing when I run this test. Only for background mining though. I converted monero to bazel so I am guessing it is because of the version of boost I used to do this.

Comment: "I meant why is the daemon crashing" <- the logs in the question are not showing "the daemon crashing", they are showing a connection error from pymonero to the daemon whilst running a test.

Comment: I thought the daemon is crashing though. The monerod logs show it stopping suddenly after receiving the interrupt signal. That is how I interpreted what was happening. That is why they couldn't connect in my mind. So is it just a more general error than what I thought?

Comment: What you have posted shows pymonero trying to call /stop_mining and that request is failing (and that is likely an error in the library or your config. If the daemon is actually *crashing*, why not show the daemon logs instead of the logs for a test failing? Also, "after receiving the interrupt signal" are you actually sending a signal or using the library to stop mining? These are very different things.

Comment: I put print statements into the daemon to see where exactly it was stopping execution and it was after it got a boost.interrupt. Okay I have modified post to have the daemon logs.

Comment: If the daemon is actually crashing on calling the RPC method /stop_mining, please capture a stack trace or core dump and open and issue on https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117465/discussion-between-jtgrassie-and-keiros).

Comment: /Are you using https://github.com/Monero-Monitor/pymonero